# How do I add columns to SharePoint to show a files version count and the size of the sum of those versions?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, filesystems, directory-structure

We've got an issue with SharePoint where we keep running out of space on our Team Drive. We know why, it’s because with versioning turned on all changes are stored and with some of our larger files (e.g. MS Access databases) that can quickly add up.

What I need is a way to either add some columns to show a count of the number of versions a file has and the size of the sum of those versions, so I can then sort and find the offending files quickly. Or are there any other solutions to quickly track down which files are adding bloat due to versioning? Powershell? I should add that I don't have network admin, only local admin on the machine.

This is the interface I'm working with, there are obviously files within each folder that these columns would reference:
[image: SharePoint Interface]

Answer (score 0):

This would require to write custom code to update as report.Please refer for more details to update according to your requirement.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/document-versions-size-report-powershell.html

Comment: Link only answer will not be helpful when its broken in future. So add the related context to the answer from the link..